# Uncaught TypeError: class constructors must be invoked with 'new' while building a neu window.app

Tags: openlayers

I'm trying to update my Openlayers application from v6.10.0 to v7.0.0 and unfortunately I get the error message "**class constructors must be invoked with 'new'**".

This happens in the part of the code where I create a new window.app.

```
window.app = {};
var app = window.app;

app.PanelCoordAndCopyright = function(opt_options) {
    
    var options = opt_options || {};
    
    var element = document.createElement('div');
    element.className = 'panel_coordandcopyright ol-control';
    element.innerHTML='Hello world';
    
    ol.control.Control.call(this, {
        element: element,
        target: options.target
    });

};
```

Exactly in the method 'call'

```
ol.control.Control.call(this, {
        element: element,
        target: options.target
    });
```

How exactly should I use this method in the v7.0.0?

Comment: ES6 classes must be extended with `class` and `super` as in https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/custom-controls.html

Comment: Is it possible to update to OL7 without rewriting everything in ES6? With OL6 it still worked in the old JS notation. Is there maybe a workflow how to apply this 'super' method to old classes?

Comment: It can be made ES5 compatible, but some rewriting will still be needed https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/11749#issuecomment-650546487  Ideally you should use `new.target` as in https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/14032#issuecomment-1222124226